# How to select data that is not inside class using js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to select data from html form like below:

```
<p class="company-detail">                      
  <span class="sb-span-left">Industry</span> : Recruiting Services<br>
  <span  class="sb-span-left">Telephone</span> : 023 993 009<br>
  <span class="sb-span-left">Email</span> : cv@camupjob.com<br>
  <span class="sb-span-left">Website</span>: www.camupjob.com<br>
</p>
```

How can I select to get **

Industry:Recruiting Services

Telephone:023 993 009

Email:cv@camupjob.com

Website:www.camupjob.com**

here is my code but cannot get the result i want

```
var data1 = :$('.company-detail').find('.sb-span-left:contains("Industry")').next().text();
```

console.log(data1);

and one more

```
var data1 = :$('.company-detail').find('.sb-span-left:contains("Industry")').next().children().remove().end().text();
console.log(data1);
```

but both dont work. please help me> thanks in advance

Comment: texts like " : Recruiting Services" will be inserted as a textnode you have to use to traverse p.childNodes and find.

Comment: edited my answer to accommodate the new question.

Answer (score 3):

You may use full word regex and then replace the words with blank space:

```js
var neededText = $('.company-detail').text().replace(/(Industry :| Telephone :|Email :|Website:)/g, '');
$("button").click(function() {
  $("d").html(neededText)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="company-detail">
  <span class="sb-span-left">Industry</span> : Recruiting Services
  <br>
  <span class="sb-span-left">Telephone</span> : 023 993 009
  <br>
  <span class="sb-span-left">Email</span> : cv@camupjob.com
  <br>
  <span class="sb-span-left">Website</span>: www.camupjob.com
  <br>
</p>
<button>Get data</button>

<d></d>
```

Comment: how can I select only one data like Industry: Recruiting Services  and not other?

Comment: @DooDoo That wasn't your question. Do you actually want all the text values without the labels or do you actually want a SINGLE text value? Please read and ensure your question is asking for what you want.

Comment: Also A.J, good answer however there is a typo in the website html. The replace function doesn't match the text.

Comment: @ user1567453 I want single text

Comment: @user1567453 : Thanks for the polite correction. I have changed the code regex to match HTML.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way would be doing it via regex.

**EDIT**

```
var data = $('.company-detail').html();
var arr = ['Industry', 'Telephone', 'Email', 'Website'];
for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    data = data.replace(/<span class="sb-span-left">[a-zA-Z]*<\/span>/, arr[i]);
}
data = data.replace(/<br>/g, '');
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `$(".company-detail br")` selector ,`$.map()`, `Node.previousSibling` , `String.prototype.replace()` with `RegExp` `/^(\s+|:)+\s/` to remove `" : "` or `": "` at beginning of selected text node, `.nodeValue`

```js
var data = $.map($(".company-detail br"), function(el, i) {
  return el.previousSibling.nodeValue.replace(/^(\s+|:)+\s/, "")
});

console.log(data)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<p class="company-detail">                      
  <span class="sb-span-left">Industry</span> : Recruiting Services<br>
  <span  class="sb-span-left">Telephone</span> : 023 993 009<br>
  <span class="sb-span-left">Email</span> : cv@camupjob.com<br>
  <span class="sb-span-left">Website</span>: www.camupjob.com<br>
</p>
```

---

Alternatively using `Element.innerHTML` , `.match()` with `RegExp` `/[0-9a-z\s.@]+(?=<br>)/ig` to match word or digit characters within `html` before `<br>` element , `.toString()` , `.trim()`

```js
console.log(
  document.querySelector(".company-detail").innerHTML
  .match(/[0-9a-z.@\s]+(?=<br>)/ig).toString().trim()
)
```

```html
<p class="company-detail">                      
  <span class="sb-span-left">Industry</span> : Recruiting Services<br>
  <span  class="sb-span-left">Telephone</span> : 023 993 009<br>
  <span class="sb-span-left">Email</span> : cv@camupjob.com<br>
  <span class="sb-span-left">Website</span>: www.camupjob.com<br>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want one long string, it is as simple as this:

```js
console.log($.trim($(".company-detail").text()));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="company-detail">                      
  <span class="sb-span-left">Industry</span> : Recruiting Services<br>
  <span  class="sb-span-left">Telephone</span> : 023 993 009<br>
  <span class="sb-span-left">Email</span> : cv@camupjob.com<br>
  <span class="sb-span-left">Website</span>: www.camupjob.com<br>
</p>
```

This is a little more flexible (and pure JS, no jQuery), taking whatever is in the span as the key in the object with the following text node as the value.

```js
(function() {
  var parent = document.getElementsByClassName('company-detail')[0];
  var childNodes = parent.childNodes;
  var obj = {};
  var lastKey = null;

  // Iterate through each of the child nodes within the company detail element
  for (var i = 0; i < childNodes.length; i++) {
    if (childNodes[i].nodeType == 1) { // It's a tag
      if (childNodes[i].tagName.toUpperCase() == "SPAN") { // It's a span
        lastKey = childNodes[i].innerHTML.trim(); // Save the text inside of the span to be used as a key
        if (lastKey.length === 0) {
          lastKey = null;
        }
      }
    } else if (childNodes[i].nodeType == 3) { // It's a text node
      var val = childNodes[i].nodeValue.trim();
      val = val.split(":"); // Split up the string based on the ":" character

      // If there was a ":" in the string, take the text after it as the value, otherwise just take it as it is
      if (val.length > 1) {
        val = val[1].trim();
      } else {
        val = val[0];
      }

      // Save the value with the last key that was extracted
      if (lastKey && val.length > 0) {
        obj[lastKey] = val;
      }
    }
  }


  console.log(obj);
})();
```

```html
<p class="company-detail">
  <span class="sb-span-left">Industry</span> : Recruiting Services
  <br>
  <span class="sb-span-left">Telephone</span> : 023 993 009
  <br>
  <span class="sb-span-left">Email</span> : cv@camupjob.com
  <br>
  <span class="sb-span-left">Website</span>: www.camupjob.com
  <br>
</p>
```